# Seg Fault using strcmp with * char

Tags: c, char, segmentation-fault, strcmp

I have this struct

```
typedef struct no
{
    char command[MAX_COMMAND_LINE_SIZE];
    struct no * prox;
} lista;

lista *listaCommand = NULL;
```

and I'm filling listaCommand with a simple function that seems to work ok, as I can read the values without any problem, but if I try to compare, like

```
strcmp(listaCommand->prox>command, ">")
```

I just get a segmentation fault, even though the value > is there, why this is happening?

Comment: How do you initialize `lista`? And `lista->command`?

Comment: Your are missing  Correct it to -> strcmp(listaCommand->prox->command, ">")

Comment: @Navnath uhhh.. clever! I though it was a typo, but you are right, if this is the actual code it is a comparison and it returns either 0 or 1.. Nice! :)

Comment: The fact that there's a problem in *this* code doesn't mean that's the only problem. @Dante003 Should Navnaths answer not solve your problem, please devise a minimal, **compilable** testcase using `strcmp` to produce your segfault.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how come nobody sees anything wrong with trying to dereference a **NULL** pointer?Either my basics are rusty or you are not seeing the elephant in the room!!

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture From what we can see, "I'm filling listaCommand with a simple function that seems to work ok". The OP *could* be inadvertently blinding us to other errors, which is why I asked for a minimal, compilable testcase...

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between the `>` operator and the `->` operator?

Answer (score 10):

```
strcmp(listaCommand->prox>command, ">")
```

Should be

```
strcmp(listaCommand->prox->command, ">")
```

In your code `listaCommand->prox>command` will be seen as a comparison operation, using the `>` operator. A comparison in C returns an integer, 0 if false, non-zero otherwise. There are good chances it will return `0`, which is not a valid memory address. Hence, the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
strcmp(listaCommand->prox>command, ">")
```

to

```
strcmp(listaCommand->prox->command, ">")
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocate memory !!!

```
typedef struct no
{
    char str[20];
    struct no * prox;
} lista;

lista *listaCommand = NULL;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    listaCommand = malloc(sizeof(lista));
    listaCommand->prox = malloc(sizeof(lista));
    strcpy(listaCommand->prox->str, "aaa");
    printf("%d\n", strcmp(listaCommand->prox->str, ">>"));

    free(listaCommand->prox);
    free(listaCommand);

    return 0;
}
```